# .NET Dependency Injection of Windows API

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

What's the right way of using Windows API with Dependency Injection best practices design? Since it interacts with the outside world, I need to abstract those calls to be able to mock them for unit testing.

Let's take these 2 functions.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

I can create a class WindowsApiService. But then these methods are static and I'm not supposed to expose static methods. I could also make them private and expose public methods that redirect to the static one, but then the method names will conflict.

What's the recommended way of handling this situation?

Comment: Build a service class and call the static methods from the service methods

Comment: Ah right. Option A is to change the name of static methods and set EntryPoint on DllImport. Option B is to have the static methods in a separate class. I guess both would work. I can create a "private static class Api" within the public Service class.